# Changing tf_prefix for a gazebo plugin?

Tags: gazebo, xacro, plugin, husky, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm working on a gazebo simulation for multiple husky robots and I'm running into some problems with my tf tree.
To set up the simulation, I'm launching each robot in a unique namespace with a matching tf prefix. This works great for separating out ROS topics and most of the transforms, however, I'm having issues with the plugins for my odometry and IMU. The issues I'm having seem to be because the frame_id of the plugins called from the .xacro file do not inherit the tf_prefix of the launch file that called them.

Here's an example:
For the default simulation with one robot, the topic **imu/data** is broadcast and has the **frame_id: base_link**. When wrapped in the namespace and tf_prefix, I can edit the  parameter to make the topic **huksy1/imu/data**. But I can't seem to change the frame id to be **frame_id: husky1/base_link**.

Does anyone have an idea on how this could be done?

Thanks all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227074/changing-tf_prefix-for-a-gazebo-plugin?/) by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've figured this one out. A lot of plugins accept a parameter for the tf frame. All I had to do was add the frameId tag. Like this:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="imu_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
    <robotNamespace>/husky1</robotNamespace>
    <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <frameId>husky1/base_link</frameId>
    <topicName>imu/data</topicName>
    <accelDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelDrift>
    <accelGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005</accelGaussianNoise>
    <rateDrift>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateDrift>
    <rateGaussianNoise>0.005 0.005 0.005 </rateGaussianNoise>
    <headingDrift>0.005</headingDrift>
    <headingGaussianNoise>0.005</headingGaussianNoise>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) with karma: 161 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1